# They will fail without earning even a dollar!

Tags: sentence-structure

Is it correct to say:

> most people forget about marketing before starting their business. so **They will fail without earning even a dollar!**

Does it make sense to you?

If not, could you please help me make it correct?

Comment: Can you give some context to help us understand the role of the sentence in the larger text?

Comment: Replace the full stop (period) after **business** with a comma or semi-colon and omit the word **will** from the sentence in order to align your tenses. (And capital M for **Most**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> most people forget about marketing before starting their business. so They will fail without earning even a dollar!

The example could become clearer if we tidy it up, as suggested.

> [M]ost people forget about marketing before starting their business[,] so [t]hey fail without earning even a dollar!

> [M]ost people forget about marketing before starting their business[; t]hey fail without earning even a dollar!

A guide related to forming compound sentences is shown below.

> A COMPOUND SENTENCE has two independent clauses joined by

> A.  a coordinating conjunction (for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so),

> B.  a conjunctive adverb (e.g. however, therefore), or

> C.  a semicolon alone.

https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sentences.aspx